# Removable vs fixed mount points in Linux

Tags: linux, nautilus, fstab

What makes a mount point removable in Linux? I am using Gentoo Linux with Gnome 3.2, and I find it annoying that some of my drives (ex: /dev/sdb) appear as removable but not the others (ex: /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd).

They are all in /etc/fstab, with the same options. They are all mounted properly at startup, they all work fine under my own folders /mnt/drive2 /mnt/drive3 /mnt/drive4. But only one of them (the first) appears in Nautilus (and in the Gnome 3 notification tray) as mountable/removable, not the others. Can I add options to my fstab to hide it? Or can I probe using udevadm or whatever? It looks strange to be able to remove/unmount fixed drives that I never need to unmount nor remove.

Any pointer would be good, thanks.

Comment: What kind of drives are you using? How are they connected to your computer? And what file system are they using?

Comment: it would help if you specified what you have mounted where. Please edit your question and add those details. Usually removables are what the name suggests: things you may remove without shutting down the system -- which include USB sticks, floppies, CDRoms, external USB disks...

Answer (score 1):

You can tell by:

```
cat /sys/block/<device>/removeable
```

This is independent of /etc/* and your hotplug manager and should be accurate on any 2.6.x+ system with a sysfs mounted on /sys

Comment: On my system (Debian sid 2012-08-12, amd64) which has only one HDD with multiple partitions, one of which I use as storage, it lists my `/sys/block/sda/removable` as `0`. Yet, the storage partition is mounted as removable. Maybe it's a gnome3 thing?

Answer (score 0):

On my system, drives become available to the user when they are Not in fstab. Perhaps try commenting them out.